# In-App purchase basic tutorial for downloadable content

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I need to integrate in-app purchase for downloadable content in my app. I am trying to display list of different player characters which can be downloaded or unlocked after purchasing the character from in-app purchase module.

Can you guys point me to proper tutorial or provide me any possible hint?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can have a pretty good base here:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

You can also check the Apple's documentation whenever you need. :)

Comment: Yes @Kio Coan. I already checked the tutorial but it's not covering downloadable contents. I need to understand of how to unlock list of assets in the game.

Comment: This tutorial covers the logic about unlocking any content with an in-app purchase.
When you get a confirmation about it, after the request, you can save that with `NSUserDefaults`. And check it, wherever you need to show the unlocked content.
For exemple, if your user got a new hat for a character you can check a `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"awesomeHatUnlocked"];` And if you value is true you can show it. :)

Comment: You mean we need to place that Hat image inside the game before we submit and just check boolean to activate or deactivate, is that? But what if I don't have proper list of what I am going to give as in-app purchases? e.g. when my app goes live and after few download I want to put an axe which can be bought by user, do I need to resubmit the app with this update or is there any other way I can do this without resubmission?

Comment: You'll need to resubmit it, because, every in-app purchase has it's own submission process, but to go through this process, you must attach this in-app purchase to a build. So, for a new in-app purchase, you must release an app update.